# Selenium 4 how to set default download directory folder?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I just upgraded my Selenium 3.x -> 4.x and trying to update my code.
How to set default download directory folder in Selenium 4?

My current code:

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": "/home/blah" # Change default directory for downloads
    "download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
```

I tried searching this on selenium website, but their search engine seems pretty bad.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": "<your download directory>",
        "download.prompt_for_download": False
})
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
```

This should work for Chrome.

If it doesn't work, other answers for older Chrome versions also set the following flag which seems to work in some cases:

- `"download.directory_upgrade": True`

Answer (score 0):

This is the path for the system default "Downloads" folder:

```
public String downloadPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\";
```